# How to setup 'tsconfig.json' to build files in 'project/src' and write output to 'project/lib'?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I tried using the following in my tsconfig.json file:

```
...

"declaration": true,
"rootDir": "./src/",
"outDir": "./lib/",

...
```

The first time I execute `tsc` it seems to work fine; but the second time I execute `tsc` I get an error where `tsc` complains that it cannot write output because it would overwrite an input file.

It seems that `tsc` is trying to include the TypeScript declaration files that are written out to my 'lib' directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just exclude the files in the `lib` folder:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "declaration": true,
      "rootDir": "./src/",
      "outDir": "./lib/",
   }
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
    ]
}
```